# Getting output stream of a process in Java

Tags: java, outputstream

In java i needed to run a process in this case node and provide user input programmatically. I could read its output like this:

```
String path = "/Users/tolymbeknurtai/desktop/projects/servlets/src/main/java/server/tester/tests/example.js";

String[] command = {"node", path};

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

reader.close();

int exitCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("process exited with code " + exitCode);
```

Once i try to access output stream and write something to it i am unable to even read the output of the program. When i run the code i doesn't finish executing. Apparently output stream is unable to write.

```
try {
    String path = "/Users/tolymbeknurtai/desktop/projects/servlets/src/main/java/server/tester/tests/example.js";

    String[] command = {"node", path};

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    writer.write("hello");
    writer.flush();

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Node.js process exited with code " + exitCode);

} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Found someone using this but in my case it doesn't work.
The javascript code in the example.js:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('',(input) => {
  console.log(input);

  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: For one thing, you should be processing stderr. You should redirect it

Comment: @g00se i didn't get you. Should i redirect stdout to stderr? I don't see how that relates to writing to stream. Could you explain more

Comment: If you write to stdin it is usually better to signal end of input immediately to ensure sub-process isn't waiting. So move `writer.close();` up just after `write`. You have ignored STDERR, read it in separate thread or use `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)` as this risks freezing a sub-process.

Comment: @user85421 oh it did work! but now the program doesn't stop. it was supposed to stop after printing the value given.

Comment: @DuncG thanks now it works. i will be more careful about stderr from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the standard-out and standard-in of the subprocess happen concurrently.  If you try to deal with all of the input and then all of the output (or vice versa), it probably will hang, at least some of the time, because the process is stuck waiting for its own output to get processed.

While you could do some of the consumption in other threads, your particular case has an easier solution.  Just make the subprocess inherit the standard-out and standard-error of Java process:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
processBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Process process = processBuilder.start();

try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        process.getOutputStream()))) {

    writer.write("hello");
}
```

The use of [INHERIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#INHERIT) will cause the subprocess to send all of its standard-otuput to the standard-output of your Java program.  Similarly, all of its standard-error will be sent to the standard-error of your Java program (which is extremely useful for troubleshooting errors and problems).

Notice the use of a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement for the BufferedWriter.  This will automatically close the BufferedWriter.  It’s both more concise and more reliable, since it effectively generates a hidden `finally` block that performs the close.

Closing a Writer or OutputStream will always flush it, so an explicit call to `flush()` is not needed.

Comment: It works perfectly standalone but stops working while deployed to to TomCat. Why would that happen?

Comment: Look for messages from the standard error of the process, in the Tomcat log.  Also, if you are catching any exceptions, log them or print them with their full stack trace.

Comment: lol i just forgot \n when writing to input. thanks anyway. sorry for bothering

Answer (score -1):

You should write the process input stream in a separate thread so you don't deadlock.

```java
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            new Thread(() -> {
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()))) {
                    writer.write("hello");
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
```

Comment: thanks. i will learn about threads too